# How to make Swiper carousel change slides by clicking space in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js

I use "swiper": "6.8.4" in React app for carousel.

I need to change slides by clicking on the "Space" button.
By default it changes by clicking on arrows.
Could you please advise me how?

```
function Carousel() {

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(KeyboardEvent.code == 'Space') {
      swiper.slideNext(); //not working
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
     swiper.slideNext(); //not working
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={classes.carouselWrapper}>
      <Swiper
        autoplay={{
          delay: 2500,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        keyboard={{
          enabled: true,
          onlyInViewport: true,
        }}
        pagination={true}
        className="mySwiper"
        cssMode={true}
        loop={false}
        scrollbar={{draggable: true}}
        modules={[Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination, Keyboard]}
        mousewheel={true}
        onSwiper={swiper => console.log(swiper)}
        slidesPerView={1}
      >
        <button>
          Change slide by clicking space
        </button>
        <SwiperSlide>
          1
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          2
        </SwiperSlide>
     </Swiper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you want to do is save `swiper` to the state so you can call `slideNext`, you can do this by using the `onSwiper` function. Then use `useEffect` to add and remove the `keydown` listener.

```
function Carousel() {
  const [swiper, setSwiper) = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keydownHandler = e => {
      if(swiper && e.keyCode == 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swiper.slideNext();
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
    }
  }, [swiper])

  return (
    <div className={classes.carouselWrapper}>
      <Swiper
        autoplay={{
          delay: 2500,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        keyboard={{
          enabled: true,
          onlyInViewport: true,
        }}
        pagination={true}
        className="mySwiper"
        cssMode={true}
        loop={false}
        scrollbar={{draggable: true}}
        modules={[Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination, Keyboard]}
        mousewheel={true}
        onSwiper={setSwiper}
        slidesPerView={1}
      >
        <button>
          Change slide by clicking space
        </button>
        <SwiperSlide>
          1
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          2
        </SwiperSlide>
     </Swiper>
    )
}
```

Keep in mind that `space` is used by browsers to scroll the page down, you probably don't want to prevent the default action.

Answer (score 0):

> document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
> if(e.keyCode == 32){
> swiper.slideNext();
> }

Can you also check if any additional library is using an event listener for spacebarr which might interrupt you're process